# Filter a SSRS report based on a R stored procedure?

Tags: r, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

Has anyone figured out how to parametrize or filter the sp_execute_external_script? I want to use that in a SSRS report with a date filter for example. 
The solution that I have found use a temp table but I would like to find a simpler solution and more reliable solution.
The goal is to remove the need for a temp table. 
Here is the code:

```
Declare @id nvarchar(3)='1'

drop table if exists   #TempTable

select * into #TempTable from (
select 0 id,1234 as Col
union
select 1 id, 12
union
select 2 id, 985
) as a1
where id=@id


EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R',
@script = N'OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet',
@input_data_1 = N'select col from #TempTable'
WITH RESULT SETS((columnName char (11)))
```

I believe that I could put this into a stored procedure and use the *id* as a parameter and then use this into SSRS. But there must be simpler way. I have tried the Dynamical sql way and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Umachandar. Your script use a parameter inside the R section of the stored procedure. In order to use a parameter for the SSRS, I need to filter  the input_data as well.

In short, the technique is to declare the variables using the @params variable and then to define each parameters separately. Inside the R section of the stored procedure, we use the variable without the @. On the other hand, inside the SQL statement part of the stored procedure, we use the variable prefixed with a @ (please see the picture bellow).

You can test this by running this code and look at the comments on the picture.

```
Declare @id nvarchar(3)='2'
Declare @anInteger int=17


drop table if exists   #TempTable

select * into #TempTable from (
select 0 id,0 as Col
union
select 1 id, 100
union
select 2 id, 200
union
select 3 id, 300
) as a1


EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
, @script = N'ThisIsThe_result <- ThisIsThe_inputSQL*aParamCalled_ID+aParamCalled_ID2'
, @input_data_1 = N'select col from #TempTable where id in(@aParamCalled_ID,1)'
, @input_data_1_name = N'ThisIsThe_inputSQL'
, @output_data_1_name = N'ThisIsThe_result'
, @params=N'@aParamCalled_ID int, @aParamCalled_ID2 int'
, @aParamCalled_ID= @id 
, @aParamCalled_ID2=@anInteger


WITH RESULT SETS((columnName char (11)))
```

Here are the comments:

[image: How to creates parameters on both the SQL statement and R code]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to specify parameter is to include a parameter or variable in the command text in the report. Do the following:

1. Create a procedure in your db which contains the sp_execute_external_script SP call. You can use sp_execute_external_script directly too. ex:

   create procedure sqlr_test_sp (@input int)
   as
   begin
       exec sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R', @script = N'OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(input);', @input_data_1 = N'', @params = N'@input int', @input = @input;
   end;
   go
2. In the SSRS report, add below as command text for the dataset. Report Builder for example will automatically create the parameter called "@input". You can set the default value and such from the parameter properties

   exec sqlr_test_sp @input